# Como pasar un valor de un script a otro

Tags: c#, unity2d

En una scena obtengo el dato ingresado por el usuario, una ves que ingresa el dato con un boton cambia de escena pero el problema es que no se como pasar ese valor a la otra escena.
la el metodo donde obtengo el valor del dato y cambio de escena

```
public void closePanel()
    {
        int numeroid = int.Parse(inputFielEditar.text);
        new InicioSesion().cambiarScene(3);
        //gameObject.

        //panelEditar.SetActive(false);
    }
```

y en el otro script que incia algunos datos de la escena intente lo siguiente para recibir el dato

```
public RegistroEjercicio(int numEjercicio)
    {
        this.numEjercicio = numEjercicio;
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        if (numEjercicio !=0)
        {
            llenar();
        }

    }
```

El problema es que no descubri como hacer para llenar ese constructor y se inicie al cambiar de escena

Comment: En unity puedes usar clases estaticas o singleton (de instancias unica) y es una de las maneras de mantener el valor entre escenas, solo cuida que al acceder, este inicializada

Answer (score 1):

Una opción muy sencilla pero insegura es el uso de `PlayerPrefs`,

Script del Set:

```
public void closePanel()
{
    int numeroid = int.Parse(inputFielEditar.text);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("NumeroId",numeroid);
    new InicioSesion().cambiarScene(3);
}
```

Script del Get:

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
   int numEjercicio = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("NumeroId");
   if (numEjercicio !=0){
      llenar();
   }
}
```